# adding new objects to array from function

Tags: javascript, object

I already have a existing array of objects like this,

```
 details = [
    {
        'asjad': {
            'age': 23,
            'area': 'permiet'
        }
    }
```

I have a function like this,

```
function addValues(_arr,_name,_age){

    _arr.push({
        _name : {
            age : _age
        }
    })

}


addValues(details,'foo',24);
```

Where I try to add values to a array of objects by passing the values of the object to be added.

But the expected output is not foo, but instead it the key is getting added as `_name`

Comment: use [_name] instead of _name in the arr.push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the above code to this. You will achieve your need.

```
function addValues(_arr,_name,_age){

    _arr.push({
        [_name] : {
            age : _age
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define an object like this in JavaScript, the key will always be a string – in your case a `_name`. To assign a dynamic variable as a key to an object, you'll need to use the bracket notation `[]`. The value, however, is evaluated as an expression. In your case, `_age` is evaluated, because it's a value and not a key.

You could easily fix with e.g. this example:

```
function addValues(_arr, _name, _age){

    var object = {};
    object[_name] = {
        age: _age
    };
    _arr.push(object);

}
```

---

These are many ways to declare an object in JavaScript:

**Inline Declaration:**

```
var object = {
   _name: '123'
};
```

→ `_name` will always be a constant string.

**Dot notation:**

```
var object = {};
var object._name = '123';
```

→ In the dot notation, `_name` will also always be a constant string.

**Bracket Notation:**

```
var object = {};
var object[_name] = '123';
```

→ In the bracket notation, `_name` is an evaluated expression. In this case, a variable name `_name`. You could also pass a string by using `object['_name']`.

**Computed property names:**

As the other answers have pointed out, with ES6 (a newer version of JavaScript, which is not fully supported by all browsers, but can be transpiled to ES5), you could also use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
var object = {
   [_name]: '123'
};
```

→ In this notation, the `_name` will be evaluated and its value will be the key in this object. Keep in mind, that you won't have IE support without transpiling this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addValues(_arr,_name,_age){

    var newItem = {};
    newItem[_name] = {};
    newItem[_name]['age'] = _age;

    _arr.push(newItem);
}
```

Comment: write some text to explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addValues(_arr,_name,_age){

    _arr.push({
        [_name] : {
            age : _age
        }
    })

}


addValues(details,'foo',24);
```

Comment: Please take the time to explain your answer for the OP and those how may come across it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`_arr.push({
     [_name] : {
        age : _age
     }
 })`

Create key value pair json you need to start key with `[]` for key interpolation